# Keeping format of text (.txt) files when reading and rewriting

Tags: python

I have a `.txt` file containing formatting elements as `\n` for line breaks which I want to read and then rewrite its data until a specific line back to a new `.txt` file. My code looks like this:

```
with open (filename) as f:    
    content=f.readlines()

with open("lf.txt", "w") as file1:
    file1.write(str(content))
    file1.close
```

The output file `lf.txt` is produced correctly but it throws away the formatting of the input file. Is there a way to keep the formatting of file 1 when rewriting it to a new file?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I maintain the format of a text file when reading a text file through Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36478337/how-do-i-maintain-the-format-of-a-text-file-when-reading-a-text-file-through-pyt)

Comment: Read whole file and write it at once :) `content = file.read()`

Comment: replace `str(content)` with `''.join(content)`

Comment: The `file1.close` part is a no-op, since there is no actual call there, and should not be there since `with` takes care of closing.

Comment: Hi! try to write your content  in bynary mode like `with open('lf.txt', 'wb')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You converted `content` to a string, while it's really a list of strings (lines).

Use `join` to convert the lines back to a string:

```
file1.write(''.join(content))
```

`join` is a string method, and it is activated in the example from an empty string object. The string calling this method is used as a separator for the strings joining process. In this situation we don't need any separator, just joining the strings.

Comment: The alternative is to loop and print. It's more scalable and allows for a `break` which the OP seems to need.

Comment: @Elazar - sorry, it's nearly impossible for programmers stumbled over Python and functional programming to use loops in such situations... :-)